# Duplicate Blender directories for .py scripts

Tags: add-on, installation

I first noticed this when I decided to try and install a
Blender Addon from the internet, for my very first time. I chose to go
with this one: [Link](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/3D_interaction/Dynamic_Spacebar_Menu) as I thought it would perhaps be somewhat
useful.

However when I try to "Install Add-on from file", using the newly acquired py file, as prompted by another guide, I get an error stating that there are duplicate instances of the .py file.  Both in my `C:/%Appdata%/Roaming/Blender`  directory, as well as in my `D:/Steam/Steamapps/Blender` directory. Both of which contain the standard folder structure with a "scripts"-folder.
This leads me to assume that one of them is not necessary and can be removed, but I don't know which one my client is utilizing and which one is disposable.

Does anybody have any idea why my Blender directory seems to be duplicated? I have installed both the Steam-version and the Retail-version in the past, should this be a clue, and also experienced a major OS-issue, where I had to reinstall and essentially clean all my programs off, yet the D:-drive remained the same throughout. I am currently using the Steam-version for reasons unknown to myself.

**EDIT:** I managed to install the script by manually adding it to my D:-directory, hence half the issue has actually been fixed. Although I am still debating on which directory can be removed and which directory should stay in my system. It is worth mentioning that there are in fact folders containing addons in both of the aforementioned directories, and Blender seems to want to include them both in it's list, even though I am clearly using the Steam Version at the moment.

Comment: why did you have your question in a block quote? You may find the [formatting page](https://blender.stackexchange.com/editing-help) helpful.

Comment: @David Ah! My apologies. I was trying to convey that the paragraphs prior to my "EDIT"-paragraph should be less emphasized, due to the fact that I somewhat already had solved my own problem at this time, though the main question still remains, of course. I found no suitable formatting option to convey as such.